# How to fix error while building iOS app from expo bare workflow

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I recently converted to expo's bare workflow to be able to access their In App Purchase package, and am having trouble building it. I run npx react-native run-ios and end up with this error:

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/louis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/motivationapp-grdlmxisqpzrubarwhyxyaornqcr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXNotifications.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EXUserFacingNotificationsPermissionsRequester.o

/Users/louis/Desktop/motivationapp/node_modules/expo-notifications/ios/EXNotifications/Permissions/EXUserFacingNotificationsPermissionsRequester.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

I don't know where to start to try and fix this, so if anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much.

Comment: Which version of expo ?

Comment: On windows, my build was 3.21.13. Today I transferred all of those files over to my mac (where the issue is taking place) to work on and my version is 3.27.6

Comment: And expo sdk version ?

Comment: I believe sdk 38 for both, as during the development of the app I used the expo documentation for 38

Comment: Have you tried Product->clean build? If that doesn't work then run this: rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: How do I go about doing product clean build, I dont know where to go for that

Comment: From xcode, open your project then on the top menu select product then clean build

Comment: Neither of those worked unfortunately.

Comment: Were you able to fix this. Facing the same after eject.

Comment: Hi Raheel, I posted the solution in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of poking and prodding I figured out a solution to my issue. I tried to build my project in xcode and was faced with similar errors. I double clicked on the errors which took me to the corresponding pod files. I noticed that all of this issues pertained to functions stating is ios 13 was available. The issue is I am using a version of xcode that goes to ios 12.1, so it makes sense why they didn't work. I then preceded to delete the problem functions, and then it worked. I'm not sure if that is the proper solution, but it worked for me and my project is working as expected.